# How to add accessibility to AJAX checking form fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, accessibility, wai-aria

I am new to accessibility. Presently I am working on the Forms. My manager asks me to integrate accessibility for fields. I've tried to applied to all fields. It's working fine. But when I get any errors it's unable to read the errors. The errors are placed below the relevant text field.

My manager told me that the screen reader software must read the errors when I click on the submit button.

Is it possible to that by using ARIA.

Answer (score 0):

1st thought : 
I am giving my idea ..Consider displaying the error message through JavaScript alert box... suppose if user submits the form without entering mandatory fields then alert box will be dasplyed .. like 
" the following errors were found while submitting a from 
1)name field is required 
2)mobile number field is required 
3)email is required like that" ........

suppose if he entered name and missed the rest of the fields display the rest of the mandatory fields in alert box "then alert box will be dasplyed .. like 
" the following errors were found while submitting a from
1)mobile number field is required 
2)email is required like that" ........

2nd thought:Include the message at the top of the form like "star(*) denotes mandatory"  and  read the form fields while cursor moves to the respective form filed like... for name read "name star".. for mobile number read "mobile number star"... since we have given the main instruction at the top of the page ....... hope this solution helps....

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Test_Cases#Description_2         go through that link.. it might helpful for accessbility